# Add A value When User Registration Is Success

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have Created a Android User Login And Registration App . I want That When a user registration is successful a Name Points And Value 0 will be added To the Database .
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDLzQ.png)

Here is my Registration Code :

```
//logging in the user
        firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        //if the task is successfull
                        if(task.isSuccessful()){
                            //start the profile activity
                            finish();
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ProfileActivity.class));
                        }else{
                            //display some message here
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Error Email Or Password",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

So in order to achieve this, use `setValue()` method directly in the reference like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
rootRef.child(userId).child("Points").setValue(0);
```

In which `userId` is the id of the specific user that is authenticated.

Comment: userId is not working . it becomes red. how to fix it?

Comment: `userId` should be one of those ids from your screeshot. Let's say you want to change the value for the first one, then in stead of `userId`, you need to use: GM3Ai.... Ok?

Comment: Sorry . UserId will be the uid when a user register.

Comment: Then you need to use: `rootRef.child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Points").setValue(0);` Ok?

Comment: Let me Try :D ok?

Comment: Yes. Keep me posted.

Comment: Didn't Worked :( .

Comment: Value and Name didn't add to database :(

Comment: No error shows . User registration is successful but Data doesn't save to database.  See the image here : https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDIk5.png

Comment: The abobe should work. The only thing you need to do is to change the userId with the userId from your authentication. Try to something like this and tell me if it works: `rootRef.child("GM3AixZUEqUXdVKfP2m7yEK2yal2").child("Points").setValue(0);`

Comment: No i don't want to update . i want that when a user registration is successful a new value and name will add to database . rootRef.child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child(‌​"Points").setValue(0‌​); this code is right . But When user registration is successful NAme and Value doesn't add to my database for The new user.